# Parsing date literal in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I  parse this type of date literal to Date object in JavaScript?

```
 var jsonDateFromServer="/Date(1333656000000+0400)/";
```

Note that Date.parse method not working here

Comment: This is not duplicate of another question, how we can convert this to Date object?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function and try like this:

```
function myDate(yourDateString) 
{
    return new Date(parseInt(yourDateString.replace('/Date(', '')));
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sbtbr5k0/1/)**

Comment: You're not handling the timezone.

Comment: @Ja͢ck:- Yes as that was not asked ;)

Comment: Without knowing the expected outcome, how can you know that for sure?

Comment: @Ja͢ck:- I dont know what you are looking for but I have just tried to parse the jsondate which OP has provided into Date format. And that was mentioned in the question!

Comment: There's no doubt that you're indeed trying to parse the given date into *something*; the question is whether it yields the expected outcome ... the question doesn't state that, though (which makes it an unclear question).

Answer (score 1):

This is a timestamp with a time zone offset. Quick and dirty solution:

```
var jsonDateFromServer="/Date(1333656000000+0400)/";
// Remove the markup
var timestamp = jsonDateFromServer.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
// Parse the base timestamp first, convert it to a notation where we can add the offset easily, parse the result
var date = new Date(new Date(parseInt(timestamp.slice(0,-5))).toUTCString() + timestamp.slice(-5));
```